# Failed in test stage gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I commiting my code to gitlab project, I get failed with test stage. Here is my test stage code:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
-chmod +x gradlew
    - ./gradlew check
```

Here is the error:

```
 $ chmod +x gradlew
 chmod: cannot access 'gradlew': No such file or directory
...
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: build/reports/: no matching files
ERROR: No files to upload
```

Is there any idea to solve this? And one more...how can I check gitlab-ci.yml it locally in my machine without gitlab-runner Or the only decision is to commit and check at gitlab itself? Thanks!

Comment: is the gradle-wrapper checked in into the repository, it sounds like there is not the file within the repository

Comment: @SimonSchrottner you mean did I commit gradlew file?